# Size of Lanthanum

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, atomic-radius

I was going through the values of atomic and covalent radii of the d-block elements.
The atomic radii of $\ce {Sc},\ce {Y}$ and $\ce {La}$ are $164, 184$ and $187$ pm respectively (Source: Wikipedia). My question is, why is the radius of Lanthanum not much bigger than Yttrium, when Yttrium and Scandium have a difference of $20$ pm?

The reason cannot be Lanthanoid contraction, since Lanthanum is before the Lanthanides. I thought it might be due to the differential shielding effect of $3$d and $4$d electrons, but I can't find any reliable sources stating this.

Comment: Empirical atomic radius column from [Wikipedia data page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_radii_of_the_elements_(data_page)) says for Sc/Y/La 160/180/195 pm, for metallic radius 162/180/187 pm

Comment: @Poutnik I referred to the Wikipedia page of each element, where the radii (empirical) are in the box to the right of the page. But even with the metallic radius values you provided, why is there a 7pm increase versus an 18 pm increase?

Comment: It is similar for Ca / Sr / Ba (met radius 197 / 215 / 222.)